# How to setup the c++ rule of three in a virtual base class

Tags: c++, c++11, polymorphism, rule-of-three

I am trying to create a pure virtual base class (or simulated pure virtual)

my goal:

1. User can't create instances of BaseClass.
2. Derived classes have to implement default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor.

My attempt:

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() {};
    /* some pure virtual functions */
private:
    Base() = default;
    Base(const Base& base) = default;
    Base& operator=(const Base& base) = default;
}
```

This gives some errors complaining that (for one) the copy constructor is private. But i don't want this mimicked constructor to be called.
Can anyone give me the correct construction to do this if this is at all possible?

Comment: It doesn't really matter if they get called or not (but it would provide useless extra overhead). The virtual base class just has to adhere to the 2 rules I stated at the top.

Comment: If the derived class should be copyable, the base class has to be copyable and the copy constructor has to be available for calling from derived class, so at least protected. The same goes for default constructor and operator=.

Comment: @CodingMash: Sure you can declare constructor private. It means that only a method of the class can construct instance with that constructor. It's done either for some constructors (to make the class non-copyable, though C++11 has `= delete` for that) or for all of them to restrict construction to a factory function. But such class is not inheritable, because the subclass constructor needs to call the base class constructor and it need to be at least protected for that. Making all constructors protected makes the class abstract.

Comment: The second requirement looks unreasonable to me. It's up to the subclass author whether they want their class to be copyable and/or assignable. What is the reason behind that requirement?

Comment: I want the user be able to create child classes, override some virtual functions and send them to a framework. The framework needs to keep that object and send out copies. The destruction of the objects will also be handled by the framework. The assignment operator is for the moment just to adhere to the rule of three.

Comment: @Minion91: That's not enforceable with base class. You could use some [concept checks](http://www.boost.org/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm). But there is more suspect here. If you have a base class with virtual methods, you suppose to use the object polymorphically. But to copy an object using it's copy constructor, you absolutely have to know it's type at compile time. To do that, the framework has to take the type as template parameter. But if it does, there is no point in having virtuals. Nor common base type for that matter.

Comment: If you want to use the object polymorphically and hand out copies of it, you will have to have abstract method `Base *clone()` that will be implemented as `return new Derived(this)` in each subclass. The framework could with a bit of template glue generate "cloners" for the objects to avoid having to define that method manually if you have really many of them.

Comment: hmmmm a virtual clone method seems quite interesting, I think I'll give that a try.

Comment: With C++11 it is the [**rule of five**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The requirement looks wrong. The reason is that virtual methods and copy constructors don't work together. Virtual methods are useful if you use the object polymorphically, that is via reference/pointer to a base class. But copy constructor always constructs object of the static type it is written as, so if you give it polymorphic object, it will *only* create the base class, not the subclass you wanted. This is called [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/274626/what-is-the-slicing-problem-in-c).

So you want to either:

- Have a templated framework that knows the type at compile time and uses copy-constructor. But this does not need any virtual methods, nor for that matter a common base type, since the code will be compiled with the specific template parameter. Compiler will complain if the type substituted does not support the operations the template tries to use, but you can slightly improve diagnostics by using some explicit checks, e.g. from [Boost.Concept Check](http://www.boost.org/libs/concept_check/concept_check.htm).
- Have a framework using polymorphic objects with base class, but that can't create copies with copy constructor, because it does not know the type to construct. There are three ways out:

  1. Have a pure virtual `Base *clone()` method, that will be implemented to do `return new Derived(this)` in each concrete subclass. You should probably wrap that in `unique_ptr` or `shared_ptr` immediately to avoid leaking the copies.
  2. Instead of copies, hand out references or smart pointers, probably `shared_ptr` in this case. It would probably be either const references/smart pointers or typed with interface that only contains methods that can't affect invariants in the framework.
  3. Make the method that inserts the objects a template, that would construct a cloner and store it along with the object. Cloner is a function `template<typename T> Base *clone(const Base *obj) { return new T(dynamic_cast<const T &>(*obj); }` (you can have a functor or a class with multiple helper methods like this). To ensure you really have correct type, the insert method should probably wrap the call to `new` as well similar to e.g. `make_shared`.

By the way, nothing of this has anything to do with rule of three. Because rule of three says that **if** default copy constructor, default assignment operator or default destructor are not good enough for the class, than none of them is. But not because compiler would require it, but because the logic *probably* does. But for most classes that want to be copyable they *are* good enough. Because in most cases you hide the resource handling in some smart pointer and just let the default copy/assignment/destructor call to it.

Comment: @JanHudec, there's a third solution that sits between the two you presented: type erasure. Using something like Boost.TypeErasure's "concepts-based polymorphism" through `any`, you can use concept constraints without having to use template functions everywhere.

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to create a pure virtual base class (or simulated pure virtual)

Sure:

> User can't create instances of BaseClass.

Easy make the destructor virtual and pure

```
class Base
{
    public:
       virtual ~Base() = 0;
};
Base::~Base(){}
```

Now you can not instantiate a member of Base.

> Derived classes have to implement default constructor, copy constructor, copy assignment operator and destructor.

You can't force any of that.
If the user does not provide any of the above the compiler will automatically generate public versions for you. But by making them private you have basically made any derived class non copyable (even if the create their own versions).

**But** in g++ there are some warnings to help you.
If you set [-Weffc++](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Dialect-Options.html#index-Weffc_002b_002b-186) and also set [-Werror](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Preprocessor-Options.html#index-Werror-940) It should generate a compile time error if you do not obey the rule of three.

Comment: Small note: Pure virtual destructor still needs implementation

Answer (score 0):

As the [Rule of the Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three) says...

> If you need to explicitly declare either the destructor, copy constructor or copy assignment 
>    operator yourself, you probably need to explicitly declare all three
>   of them.

In your example of abstract class with the inheritance hierarchy, you would have to make the destructor, copy constructor and the copy assignment operator your self. Do not declare either of them as private as you restrict their usage out of the class.

```
class Base
{
 /* some pure virtual functions */
 public:
     Base() ;
     Base(const Base& base) ;
     Base& operator=(const Base& base) = default;
     virtual ~Base() {};
} ;
```

As a matter of fact, assignment operator is not passed on in inheritance.

Comment: This does not prevent that classes can omit certain function implementations

Comment: can you make your point clear?
I am unable to get it

Comment: I want to make sure that someone who uses my classes has to implement those 4 methods

Comment: You mean you want that someone who derives the classes from `Base` creates implementations in the respective child classes as well?

Comment: yes, exactly that

Comment: Virtual assignment operator is useless. If would assign from base class, which you probably don't want and would be hidden by the proper assignment operator.